# talend - name of components in tStatCatcher

Tags: talend

I'm having trouble displaying the label of my components properly in tStatCatcher.  I have renamed my components label but upon logging of tStatCatcher's origin field, the name is still the previous one.

E.g. Renamed my tDatabaseInput from MY_QUERY from tDatabaseInput1

tStatCatcher is still displaying tDatabaseInput1. It should be the new name MY_QUERY.

Anyone can provide assistance.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best answer.  But I'm sticking to this implementation for now unless someone shared a much better way.

I created a routine java class with a method that maps the from the tStatCatcher's `row.origin` to my hardcoded list of label names:

```
public static String mapToLabel(String uniqueName) {
     switch(uniqueName) {
         case "tDatabaseInput1":
             return "MY_QUERY";
         default:
             return "--not mapped";
     }
}
```

Then I called this method on my tMap's expression editor.

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete the technical name of the component, it will always appear in logs as tComponent_1, to ensure unicity.
What you can do is adding MY_QUERY to the technical name, using `__UNIQUE_NAME__`
It will still not appear in your log, but you'll be able to see that MY_QUERY is linked to tComponent_1.

For example :

[[image]]

[image]